# what does "-[1, ]" mean in " if(!-[1, ] && !window.XMLHttpRequest)"?

Tags: javascript

I find the code below , but I can't understand this.

```
if (!-[1, ] && !window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    document.execCommand("BackgroundImageCache", false, true);
}
```

What does `if(!-[1,])` mean ? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a hack to detect old Internet Explorer. `-[1,]` is `-1` in modern browsers (so `false` with `!`) but `NaN` in old IE (`true` negated). The first version to return correct result is IE9.

Comment: Indeed -- [`document.execCommand("BackgroundImageCache", false, true)`](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=BackgroundImageCache) seems to be used widely as an IE compatibility hack.

Comment: To me, `!-[1, ]` yields `false` in chrome but `true` even in IE9.

Comment: @DavidHedlund I guess you have some compatibility mode on or render the page in quirks mode. IE9 has pretty good Ecmascript support and should (and does for me) return the same result as Chrome.

Comment: @duri: you're right, it appears quirks mode was mandated by the particular site i was browsing. never mind, then.

Answer (score 4):

<strike>That exact code will never yield anything other than `false`, so it is nonsensical as entered. I assume that this is rendered output and that depending on some serverside variable, it may sometimes be something different.</strike>

Seeing as it uses `window.XMLHttpRequest`, I realize it could also be some poor form of browser check. `[1,]` creates an array, but the trailing comma will make the array treated differently in Chrome and Internet Explorer. Chrome will recognize this as an array of only one number, which could be implicitly cast to a number, whereas IE will consider it to be an  array containing two items, which can't be cast to a number.

`-[1,0]` will yield `NaN` in all browsers. `-[1]` will yield `-1` in all browsers. Hence `-[1,]` will yield `NaN` in IE (and hence execute the code), and `-1` in other browsers (and not execute the code).

This is a terrible hack. Don't use it.

If you want to find out whether `window.XMLHttpRequest` will work, test for that specifically, and not for anything else.

Answer (score 0):

This is particularly bad code:

`-[1, ]` Results to the number -1.

`!-[1, ]` would always be false.

Since the [] implies an array, this is bad, cause if you had more than one value in that array, the `-` would give you a NaN.